# Select2 and Meteor.js how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-select2

I've only been using javascript / jquery and meteor for a couple of weeks now, so forgive me for asking what will be a simple question.

I'm trying to use Select2 in my Meteor.js app, and can't figure out how to get it working. I have installed natestrauser:select2 in my project and my jsfiddle shown just won't work. https://jsfiddle.net/jt0jr9uk

```
Template.createjob.onCreated( function() {
    $("clientlist").select2({
        placeholder: "Select a client",
        allowClear: false,
    });
});
```

And html:

```
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
<select id="clientList" class="form-control">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="aberfitch">Abercrombie & Fitch</option>
    <option value="bent">Bentley</option>
    <option value="barb">Barbour</option>
    <option value="dcsh">DC Shoes</option>
    <option value="echo">ECHO United</option>
</select>
```

I'm using bootstrap also. Which I've added to my project. And basically I just want the single select box as shown here https://select2.github.io/examples.html#single

Should I be using any imports, or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all, on js level you tried to select an id, named clientlist

```
Template.createjob.onCreated( function() {
    $("clientlist").select2({....
```

However, on html level, your id is defined in camelCase

```
<select id="clientList" class="form-control">
```

Second of all, when you select an id, you should use `#` sign before the id, what I mean is your jquery should look like this to achive the desired result:

```
   Template.createjob.onCreated( function() {
      $("#clientList").select2({
          placeholder: "Select a client",
          allowClear: false,
      });
    });
```

You need to import jquery on top of the document if you use meteor >1.3 as

```
import { $ } from 'meteor/jquery';
```

As a final suggestion, I would use `Template.createjob.onRendered()` instead for `Template.createjob.onCreated()`

> The template rendered callback is fired after the DOM is rendered on
>   screen. The created callback is fired when the Template is
>   instantiated but not yet rendered

Check the following link for the full explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783762/7235661

Comment: I can't believe how I overlooked the camelcasing! 
Thank you Cagri. I've also changed to onRendered() as per your suggestion. Makes sense after reading the link you provided.